# Robocopy does not overwrite when copying a single file, even with /IS

Tags: windows, robocopy

I can't make robocopy to overwrite a single file, even with the **/IS** flag on:

```
C:\>robocopy.exe "\\srv1\D\SRCFOLDER"  "\\srv2\D\DSTFOLDER" "test.txt" /IS
```

I always got:

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         1         0         1         0         0         0
```

Is anyone able to overwrite a single file? Or is it some kind of robocopy 'bug' ?

**Note:** I use robocopy to copy a single file because I need the bandwidth control option `/IPG:xxx`
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** thanks to Lenniey comment I added some info, here the complete output:

```
Started : Wednesday, January 18, 2017 11:42:23 AM
 Source : \\srv1\D\SRCFOLDER\
   Dest : \\srv2\D\DSTFOLDER\

  Files : test.txt

Options : /V /TS /FP /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /IS /IT /R:0 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       1    \\srv1\D\SRCFOLDER\
          modified            36.4 m 2017/01/17 09:15:21    \\srv1\D\SRCFOLDER\test.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
Files :         1         0         1         0         0         0
Bytes :   36.40 m         0   36.40 m         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
Ended : Wednesday, January 18, 2017 11:42:23 AM
```

Even if the status is **modified** the file is skipped!
I got crazy to reproduce this 'bug', the only way I found was to rename the destination file **\\srv2\D\DSTFOLDER\test.txt** to something else, then rename it back to **test.txt**. After the rename the file is skipped forever.

Comment: Try `/is` and `/it` in combination. Also use `/v` (and maybe `/ts` `/fp`) to display additional information.

Comment: Thanks @Lenniey, to reproduce this 'bug' you need to rename the destination file, and then rename it back to its original name, in this way you make robocopy skip the file!

Comment: So...did you solve it? Can't really follow you there

Comment: Is not solved, but I can workaround avoiding renaming destination files.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to do _exactly_?

Comment: In outer synthesis: try to execute two times this command: `robocopy.exe "\\srv1\D\SRCFOLDER"  "\\srv2\D\DSTFOLDER" "test.txt" /R:0 /IS /IT /NODCOPY /IPG:10`. The second time the file is not copied.